# Necessity of gracefully ending a thread

Tags: multithreading, kill-process

If I am building a multithreaded application, all its threads would automatically get killed when I abort the application.

If I want a thread to have a lifetime equal to that of the main thread, do I really need to gracefully end the thread, or let the application abort take care of killing it?

**Edit**: As threading rules depend on the OS, I'd like to hear opinions for the following too:

1. Android
2. Linux
3. iOS

Comment: You need to take care of your threads. Use an inter-threads communication mechanism at exit to signal end of the main thread to other threads, then join the threads and wait until they're stopped. This is the "clean" way. And first, ask yourself if you really need threads at all (if it's doing I/O, you'd better use something else most of the time)

Comment: what if i use a blocking queue implementation, which is waiting on a push?
I don't want to give an exit token in the queue.

Comment: why? it's the cleanest approach

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the thread is doing.

When a thread is killed, it's execution stops at any point in the code, meaning some operations may not be finished, like

- writing a file
- sending network messages

**But** the OS will

- close all handles the application owns
- release any locks
- free all memory
- close any open file
- etc...

So, as long as you can make sure that all your files etc. are in a consistent state, you don't have to worry about the system resources.

I know [this is true for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686722(v=vs.85).aspx), and I would be very surprised if it was different on other OSes. The time when a application that didn't release all resources could affect the entire system is long gone, fortunately.

Comment: Awesome! But in the following scenario:
 A thread is constructed in a class constructor, and killed in the destructor. We can implement some logic where the destructor halts till sending messages or file writing has been done!
If we halt the destruction, we halt the killing till our work is done, considering the class has an application lifetime.

Comment: Also, I still have to get assurance regarding mobile OSes

Answer (score 1):

No.  With most non-trivial OS, you do not need to explicitly/gracefully terminate app-lifetime threads unless there is a specific and overriding need to do so.

Just one reason is that you cannot always actually do it with user code. User-level code cannot stop a thread that is running on another core than the thread requesting the stop.  The OS can, and does.

Your linux/Windows OS is very good indeed at stopping threads in any state on an core and releasing resources like thread stacks, heaps, OS object handles/fd's etc. at process-termination. It's had millions of hours of testing on systems world-wide, something that your own user code is very unlikely to ever experience.  If you can do so, you should let the OS do what it's good at.

In other posts, several cases have been made where user-level termination of a thread may be unavoidable.  Inter-process comms is one area, as are DB connections/transactions.  If you are forced into it by your requirements, then fine, go for it but, otherwise, don't try - it's a waste of time and effort writing/testing/debugging thread-stop code to do what the OS can do effectively on its own.

Beware of premature stoptimization.